# Garbage accessibility logs in Xcode console output

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, accessibility

At certain point I used Accessibility Inspector (from Xcode -> Open developer tool -> Accessibility Inspector) while running my app in simulator, and ever since the Xcode console is cluttered with accessibility logs, no matter if Inspector is launched or not:

```
objc[33601]: Class ___MKPlaceBusinessInfoItemAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11f4817b0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11ff15f00). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

And there are hundreds of lines of this for all different classes, so it's very hard to find some useful output.

I've tried adding `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` with `disable` value in Product>>Scheme>>Edit Scheme...>>Run as Environment variable, but that doesn't help.

Anyone knows how to turn it off?